# React-Native: How to add an icon on the top bar that makes the popToTop?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I would like to add a button in the topBar that does popToTop only in two screens of the navigation stack. I tried to do this, but apparently the navigation does not work.

My code is as follow:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App({navigation}) {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>

      <Stack.Navigator>

        <Stack.Screen
          name='MyMusic'
          component={TabNavigator}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name='Search song'
          component={SongScreen}
          options={{
            headerRight: () => (
              <AntDesign
                name='home'
                color='white'
                size={25}
                style={{justifyContent: 'center', padding: 15}}
                onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop())}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name='Search artist'
          component={ArtistScreen}
          options={{
            headerRight: () => (
              <AntDesign
                name='home'
                color='white'
                size={25}
                style={{justifyContent: 'center', padding: 15}}
                onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop())}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

But trying on the emulator this error occurs, after clicking:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.dispatch')
```

**EDIT**: `App.js`'s code. I marked with the comment 'not work' the interested line:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import TabNavigator from './components/navigation/TabNavigator';
import SongScreen from './components/screens/SongScreen';
import ArtistScreen from './components/screens/ArtistScreen';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const colorStatusBar = Platform.OS === 'android' ? '#4527A0' : '#673AB7';

export default function App() {

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar
        backgroundColor={colorStatusBar}
      />
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name='MyMusic'
          component={TabNavigator}
          options={{
            title: 'MyMusic',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#673AB7',
            },
            headerTintColor: 'white',
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name='Search song'
          component={SongScreen}
          options={{
            title: 'Song Video & Lyrics',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#673AB7',
            },
            headerTintColor: 'white',
            headerRight: () => ( 
              <AntDesign
                name='home'
                color='white'
                size={25}
                style={{ justifyContent: 'center', padding: 15 }}
                onPress={() => navigation.popToTop()} //<---not work
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name='Search artist'
          component={ArtistScreen}
          options={{
            title: 'Artist Details',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#673AB7',
            },
            headerTintColor: 'white',
            headerRight: () => ( 
                  <AntDesign
                    name='home'
                    color='white'
                    size={25}
                    style={{ justifyContent: 'center', padding: 15 }}
                    onPress={() => navigation.popToTop()} //<---not work
                  />
                ),
              }}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
```

Comment: try the solutions I pointed out and let me know

Comment: @Subha I tried your suggestions by substituting `navigation.popToTop()` but still it gives me equally error. `StackActions` was imported correctly. The problem only happens if I put the `navigation` commands in the `App.js` which includes stack management. In the other files I also use `navigation` commands and they work perfectly

Comment: Can you please share you App.js code. The complete code including imports etc thanks

Comment: I edited my answer based on your feedback. Please check now

Comment: I am sure it will work now and if so please accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: @Subha I followed your tips, now a different error comes out: `Error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?`. while I edit the question by adding full `App.js`

Comment: did you `npm install @react-navigation/native` ? If you did and copied my code, this must work.

Comment: @Subha I installed it, but the error comes out

Comment: In that case try setting the `headerRight: ` inside the screens and not in App.js. I hope this works, if this does not work then we will have to implement a longer hack given that `navigation` is not available in your App.js.

Comment: @Subha I had also thought about this solution, but I would not know how to make changes to the TopBar inside the other screens being managed in the App.js

Comment: I can help with that. I am amending the answer

Comment: @Subha I'm sorry, but I have some bad news. I tried to do what you told me, but the icon does not appear. I also tried with a normal React Native button but it doesn't appear. The problem may be that songscreen is a function? I don't think

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to access the navigation props in App.js it is showing as undefined.

You must use the `useNavigation` hook.

In your terminal `npm install @react-navigation/native`

Once you installed the package then adjust your App.js like so

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function App() {

const navigation = useNavigation();

//here is the rest of your code
}
```

[Here is the official docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation)

**ALTERNATE APPROACH IN CASE THE ABOVE DOES NOT WORK**

Add header in the screens directly and not in App.js using **navigationOptions**. Here is how to do it in the SongScreen for example

```
//All IMPORT statements goes here

const SongScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  //All your SongScreen CODE goes here 
};

SongScreen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    headerRight: () => {
      return (
        <AntDesign
          name='home'
          color='white'
          size={25}
          style={{ justifyContent: 'center', padding: 15 }}
          onPress={() => navigation.popToTop()}
        />
      ); 
    },
  };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    //All your SongScreen STYLES goes here 
});

export default SongScreen;
```

Comment: @outgg Just give me some good news now. This should work if the AntDesign component is okay.